# Advance Active Record Joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models

```
Items 
Customisations
Property Maps
```

with Associations like so --

```
**Customizations**
belongs_to :item
has_many :property_maps, as: :mappable

 **Items**
  has_many :customizations
  has_many :property_maps, as: :mappable

**Property Maps**
belongs_to :mappable, polymorphic: true
```

I've implemented a pretty decent filtering system taking into consideration just Items and properties like so --

```
    def self.filter_in_properties(property_ids, group_name)
           joins(:property_maps).joins('JOIN property_maps '+group_name+' ON '+group_name+'.mappable_id = items.id  AND '+group_name+'.property_id IN ('+property_ids.to_s.tr('[', '').tr(']', '').tr('"', '') +')')
    end
```

and I call them in the controller like so --

```
@items_without_pagination.filter_in_properties(params[:color_filter], 'color_filter').uniq
```

How can I do build out a filtering system so that when for example a user searches for the color red, it not only returns items that have the property red but also return items which have customizations with the property red?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `joins` to include customizations in your query in conjunction to `filter` on items/customizations with the color `'red'`:

```
Item.joins(:customizations).where("items.color = '?' OR customizations.color='?'", 'red').uniq
```

This will return items where either `item.color` is `'red'` or any of `item.customizations` is red.

Note that `color` should be a column in both the `items` and `customizations` tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much what I ended up doing --

```
def self.filter_in_properties(property_ids, group_name)
    return all if property_ids.blank?
    joins('LEFT JOIN customizations as prop_customizations ON prop_customizations.item_id = items.id')
.joins('LEFT JOIN property_maps '+group_name+' ON '+group_name+'.mappable_id = items.id')
    .joins('LEFT JOIN property_maps '+group_name+'_customization ON '+group_name+'_customization.mappable_id = prop_customizations.id')
    .where('('+group_name+'.property_id IN ('+property_ids.to_s.tr('[', '').tr(']', '').tr('"', '') +')) OR ('+group_name+'_customization.property_id IN ('+property_ids.to_s.tr('[', '').tr(']', '').tr('"', '') +'))' ).distinct
end
```